# URL + htmlentities ? what to think about this?

Tags: php, security, url, urlencode, html-entities

I asked a question in an another forum related to urlencode(), when a guy appeared saying briskly it is absolutly required to make use of htmlentities on top of it, and also suggesting I should do that everytime I write an URL. "To be valid and secure he said". I do not see why it could be a security issue. Here is the code he mentionned :

```
echo '<a href="index.php?' . htmlentities('page=encode&code='.urlencode($code).'&login='.urlencode($login).'&codeconf=' . urlencode($codeconf)) . '">';
```

Php Manual indeed mentions htmlentities. But there are no further explanations:

> Note ... PHP supports changing the argument separator to the W3C-suggested semi-colon through the arg_separator .ini directive. Unfortunately most user agents do not send form data in this semi-colon separated format. A more portable way around this is to use & instead of & as the separator. You don't need to change PHP's arg_separator for this. Leave it as &, but simply encode your URLs using htmlentities() or htmlspecialchars().

I replaced **"&"** by **&amp ;** , I validated my page in W3C validator and it came out OK.

I am still concerned about this htmlentities issue.

1. Is there any good reason why whe should use htmlentities in URL's ?
2. If yes, does this apply to all types of URL's ?
3. If yes, is it for security reasons ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not about HTML entities *in URLs*. This is about you putting arbitrary data into HTML, which means you need to HTML escape any special characters in it. That this data happens to be a URL is irrelevant.

1. You need to escape any arbitrary data you put into the URL with `urlencode` to preserve characters with a special meaning in the URL.
2. The arbitrary blob of data you get from step one needs to be HTML escaped for the same reasons when put into HTML. As you see in your example, there's an `&` in your data which is *required* to be escaped to `&amp;` by HTML rules.

If you did not use the URL in an HTML context, there'd be no need to HTML escape it. HTML entities have no place in a URL. A URL in an HTML context must be HTML escaped though, like any other data.

Comment: Thks! It becomes clearer. So if I do not mistake, when we put the URL into an html context (<a href f. i.) It must be escaped. It is  still a bit difficult to figure out what would be a non-html context, as in php generates html, would you have examples ? Thks too for your comment on **&** , that guy-who-knows-everything did not tell me.

Comment: Well, yes, PHP is used a lot for generating HTML, but it is not its only use. When you generate that URL and send it in an email (from PHP), it is not an HTML context. When you insert data into a database, it is not an HTML context. When generating CSV files, it is not an HTML context. There are *many* cases that are not HTML related at all that are done with PHP all the time.

Comment: Read: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Comment: +1 . The Great Escapism's a must! Gonna digest it bit by bit.One more question if you do not mind: as said earlier, in html context it is required to escape, but in the following example language cookie choice : `<a href='index.php?page=lang&amp;language=fr')."'>Site en français</a>` ... why should I escape since 1)there is no user input 2) I checked that page 100 times it is said to be valid 3) I check the cookie 'es' or 'fr' to see if it hasn't been modified,, before accepting it. Thanks.

Comment: The end-goal is simply to generate valid HTML syntax. You can write valid HTML by hand, if you know all the escaping rules. If you have only static content which never changes, of course you can simply write it by hand without having to escape it every time. Only if you have dynamic content which you cannot be 100% sure will keep the HTML/URL/whatever syntax intact do you need to run it through an appropriate escaping function.